# I don't understand why my for loop gives an awkward output

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, logic, knapsack-problem

unfortunately... I asked about exactly this question yesterday about another error, hopefully, I don't have those errors anymore but I still have this awkward output, like some sort of numbers depending on the array element like -4221565 or -4647963, etc... Until now I think that my array appending part works correctly, I tried that. But I guess something wrong about the -1 in the condition but I can't name it. For loop is also another place I would say ok. I am trying to solve this since 3.00 AM then procrastinate it, then tried it... And the deadline is 7.04.2020(TODAY) 22.00 so I am starting to getting crazy. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.So this is the question(İnputs does not have to be 15 it can be up to 15):

You have to transport a maximum of 15 different loads from one port to another. The carrying capacity of a cargo ship, which will transport those loads, is 50 tons. Loads are enumerated and the information about the weight of every load is given as input.

Suppose that the weight of every load is smaller than or equal to 50 tons and greater than 0.

You will read the weight of every load from the input in a single line. Your input will end with a -1. You will print the number of trips necessary.

Sample Input:

50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 -1

Output:15

Input:
20 25 25 36 37 25 20 10 50 9 16 45 32 10 25 -1

Output:
11

Input:
14 16 50 10 10 19 45 40 32 24 25 47 10 12 25 -1

Output:
9

Input:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 -1

Output:
3

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   int w,i,sum,index;
    int list[15];
    w = 1;
    index = 0;
    do
    {   scanf("%d",&w);
        list[index] = w;
        index++;
    }while(w != -1);
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 15;i++)
    {
        sum +=list[i];
    }
        sum = sum / 50;
        printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your loop stores `-1` in the non-existent 16th element of a 15-element array, and in so doing invokes *undefined behavior*. Change your loop to be a while-loop instead, specifically, `while (index < 15 && scan("%d", &w) == 1 && w != -1) { list[index++] = w; }`

Comment: Change the do-while to `while(1) { scanf("%d", &w); if(w==-1) break; list[index] = w; index++} `

Comment: In the case of less than 15 integers being entered when looping through and summing the values you are still summing the values in the array that are not set to a value. You are summing undefined values and that is one reason you are getting weird negatives. you should only be looping one less than index in the summing for loop.

Comment: And, related, you don't need an array for this anyay, you could just as easily put `sum += w;` in the loop instead of storing in an array, bumping a counter and using that as your count-of-elements later on (which you don't seem to be using anyway, and that itself is a flaw).

Comment: The task is not formulated very well either. It does not say that you can pick them in any order you want, but it does not forbid it either. And if it is allowed to pick them in any order, then 7 trips is possible for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you are passing boundaries of array `-1` will be 16th element of array which wrong. you need at least `int list[16];`.

but your solution is wrong , you are divining loads to place them in cargo ship which judging by given input and output. for example if there are 30 and 10 in one ship you can't divide a 20 load to two 10 loads in order to place max of 50 ton in the ship.

what you need is :

1. consider a ship with `0` ton
2. add load to it while sum of load are lower or equal to `50`
3. if with new load added sum of current ship goes upper than `50`  `counter_ship++` and then add that load to a new load.

```
int main(void) {
    int w;
    int sum = 0;
    int ship_counter = 0;
    scanf("%d", &w);

    while (w != -1) {
        if (sum + w > 50)
        {
            ship_counter++;
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum += w; 
        scanf("%d", &w);
    }
    if (sum != 50)
        ship_counter++;
    printf("%d", ship_counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its much more simple and clear to understand in that way and thanks to you I am able to submit my code. I will keep trying to solve it with a do-while loop, array , for loop ... All possible ways I guess. After get some sleep.

Comment: @IDK feel free , there is no need for thanks , but if this was helpful accept the answer.

Comment: *"you can divide a 20 load to two 10 loads"* Did you mean **can't**? You are on point but I guess, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues, and I didn´t felt well to improve what still got logical issues in it, so I do something I normally do not (because apparently you seem to be very stressed about that and you are in a hurry) and provide you my own version of how I did the task:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LOADS 15
#define MAX_CAP 50

int main()
{
    int w[MAX_LOADS+1];
    int trips = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int loads = 0;
    int rest = 0;

    printf("Enter the Weights of the Loads:\n");    

    while(i < (MAX_LOADS + 1))
    {
        scanf(" %d",&w[i]);
        printf(" ");
        if(w[i] == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        sum = sum + w[i];

        loads++;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("%d Loads have a weight of %d tons.\n", loads, sum);

    if(sum <= MAX_CAP)
    {
         printf("The amount of needed trips are: 1");
    }
    else
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < loads; i++)
         {
             if(w[i] == MAX_CAP)
             {
                 w[i] = 0;
                 trips++;
                 continue; 
             }
             else if(w[i] < MAX_CAP && w[i] > 0)
             {
                 rest = MAX_CAP - w[i];
                 w[i] = 0;

                 for(int j = 0; j < loads; j++)
                 {
                     if(i == j)
                     continue;

                     if(w[j] == rest)
                     {
                        w[j] = 0;
                        break;
                     }
                     else if(w[j] < rest && w[j] > 0)
                     {
                        rest = rest - w[j];
                        w[j] = 0;
                     } 

                     if(rest == 0)
                     {
                        break;
                     }
                 } 

                 trips++;
             }
         }

         printf("The amount of needed trips are: %d", trips);
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Output / Execution 1:

```
Enter the Weights of the Loads:    
10 20 40 -1                    

3 Loads have a weight of 70 tons.
The amount of needed trips are: 2
```

Output / Execution 2:

```
Enter the Weights of the Loads:          
50 50 50 50 50 -1   

5 Loads have a weight of 250 tons.              
The amount of needed trips are: 5
```

Output / Execution 3:

```
Enter the Weights of the Loads:  
10 10 10 10 10 -1   

5 Loads have a weight of 50 tons.                               
The amount of needed trips are: 1
```

Comment: I can give you a hint: OP's test case 2

Comment: @ArdentCoder So now I´ve corrected it. What do you think about it?

Comment: The logic is flawed again. Lots of exaggerated code as well.

Comment: For your limited inputs only. See what happens to your output when, for example, input is `20 40 40 -1`. It will give `2` because `100 = 50 * 2`. But do you think those loads can be transported in 2 cargos?

Comment: @ArdentCoder No, it´s intended to do so and Yes, that´s what I think: *"The carrying capacity of a cargo ship, which will transport those loads, is 50 tons. ... Suppose that the weight of every load is smaller than or equal to 50 tons and greater than 0."* - That said, those loads can be transported in 2 shipments.

Comment: If you couldn't understand that phrasing of the question, they have provided you with test cases. I can make it more clear to make you realize what's going wrong in your code: *Those loads are **discrete** items.* The mistake which I pointed out is the reason why your code still fails for **TestCase2** given in the question.

Comment: @ArdentCoder I know it know. :-)

Comment: @ArdentCoder So, now I corrected the code that it takes care to treat each load as not being divisible. Anyway, It still do not match to the example´s output although everything shall be ok, now. Maybe is the reference defective... F.e. if I input `30 40 40 40` - it shows `4` trips, which is correct.

Comment: Your edit does not show any significant changes. It will again fail **TestCase2**. *Re: "Maybe is the reference defective..."* Hanie's code passed all test cases as commented by the OP under her answer. The only reason I didn't upvote that answer is due to the contradiction in the second paragraph or maybe I couldn't comprehend what she meant to explain. I have already told where you are going wrong, so you can refer her answer and find a way to correct your code.

Comment: @ArdentCoder One last call: My answer is **not** wrong. hanie´s solution might solve the task by the author´s intention (which is not really clear) but it isn´t the most efficient one to solve the problem without dividing loads. Her code is only comparing subsequent loads, not if any of the available loads could be added to one shipment capable to hold it. That´s why my solution requires much less shipments. You can´t say it is wrong since the author itself did not clearly stated the permissions and restrictions of the relative task.

Comment: *Re: "but it isn´t the most efficient one"*: Efficiency was not requested by the OP. *Re: "Her code is only comparing subsequent loads"*: Maybe cargos come in a *queue*, but as a coder we may not already know that. That is why, they have provided **samples** in order to comprehend the question better. *Re: "the author itself did not clearly stated the permissions and restrictions"* Again, the author has provided test cases and I simplified it for you giving two clues: **discrete** and **queue**, with explanation. I don't understand how you would submit that code which still fails TestCase2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the array. Then you need to check against a threshold amount. If it surpasses that you add a container.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int* xp, int* yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

// Function to perform Selection Sort 
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, j, min_idx; 

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) { 

        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array 
        min_idx = i; 
        for (j = i + 1; j < n-1; j++) 
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx]) 
                min_idx = j; 

        // Swap the found minimum element 
        // with the first element 
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]); 
    } 
} 

int main()
{   int w,i,sum,index;
    int list[15];
    w = 1;
    index = 0;
    do
    {   scanf("%d",&w);
        list[index] = w;
        index++;
    }while(w != -1);

    selectionSort(list,index);

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) 
        printf("%d ", list[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 

    int ans=0;
    int threshold=0;
    for(int i=0; i<index; ++i){
        if(threshold + list[i]<=50){
            threshold+=list[i];
        }
        else {
            threshold = list[i];
            ++ans;
        }
    }
    ans++;
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorting is not necessary

Comment: It is required for logical purpose.

Comment: I am new to language so I need to have a little research to understand this. I will take my time. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the do-while loop to a while like this:

```
while(w != -1 && index < 15)
{   scanf("%d",&w);
    list[index] = w;
    index++;
}
```

This way you avoid writing beyond array's boundary.

Then, the condition of the for loop could be:

`for(i = 0;i < index; i++)`

(value of index comes from the previous loop, and it's only up to the next item of the last inserted).
So you 're summing up the items that actually had an input, not the whole array.

Of course you could do without an array, as others commented.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, it clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 15
int main()
{  
    /* Let's define variables here. */
    int i=0,j=0 ;
    int input;
    int weights[MAX_SIZE];
    int  numberOfTrips = 0;
    int sum = 0;

  /* Inputs is taken  here from usre, Max = 15 */
    printf("Input:\n");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    while(input != -1){
        if (i< MAX_SIZE){
            if (input <= 50 &&  input>= 0){
                weights[i] = input;
                i = i  +1;

            } else printf("Wrong Input! \nPlease Enter value between 0 and 50\n");
        }

        else printf("You reach MAX_SIZE, please Enter -1 to see the Output");


        scanf("%d",&input);

    }

    printf("\n");
   /* We are going  will count the number of trips necessary*/
    if(input == -1){
        if (weights[0] != 0){
             /* Let's test the first value*/
          numberOfTrips = numberOfTrips +1;
        }
        sum= weights[0];
        for (j = 1; j<i; ++j){
          sum = sum +weights[j];

          if (sum>50){
            numberOfTrips = numberOfTrips +1;
            sum = weights[j];
          }
        }

    }
 /*Finally, let's print the output here.*/
    printf("Output:\n");
    printf("%d",numberOfTrips);

    return 0;
}
```